# Scaling up a client vpn

Tags: cloud, autoscaling

We are setting up an ikev2 client vpn using strongswan. So far we have managed to setup a single server using letsencrypt certificate with eap-radius authentication method. We are able to connect to our server without any issue. Now we want to auto-scale the vpn so that the server gets scaled up or down depending on the number of users connected to the server but how do we do it?

**What would be the best approach to achieve this?**

Comment: It depends. Generally an API towards your cloud solution.

Comment: @vidarlo can you please explain?

Comment: No, you don't have *nearly* enough information to be able to answer. But generally you need to detect load level and scale based on this. How to perform this scaling depends on the solution.